# How do I prove the formula for distance from point to line $\mathbf{(p_2-p_1)} \times \mathbf{(p_1-p_0)} / ||\mathbf{(p_2-p_1)} ||$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

the distance from a line in the plane given by the equation $ax+by+c=0$ to a point $\mathbf{p_0} (x_0, y_0)$ is:

$$\operatorname{distance}(ax+by+c=0, (x_0, y_0)) = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}. $$

I clearly understand all above.

per a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840218), suppose the line $ax+by+c=0$ goes through two points $\mathbf{p_1} (x_1, y_1)$ and $\mathbf{p_2} (x_2, y_2)$, the distance can also be computed with $\mathbf{p_1}$ and $\mathbf{p_2}$.

$$\mathbf{(p_2-p_1)} \times \mathbf{(p_0-p_1)} / ||\mathbf{(p_2-p_1)} ||$$

where $||\mathbf{(p_2-p_1)}||$ denotes the L2 norm of it and $\times$ means cross product.

How do I prove the statement algebraically?

By "algebraically" I mean something like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#An_algebraic_proof), because cross product is only for 3d vectors in terms of geometry which indicates it might be difficult to produce some geometric arguments to prove the formula above.

However, the proof doesn't have to be an algebraic one, a geometric one is also appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what $\times$ means in this context?

Comment: @Vincent Updated. Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: Ok right. But then should the first term in the cross product not be $p_2 - p_0$ rather than $p_2 - p_1$? (with boldface)

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "prove <something> algebraically"? Do you want a proof that only uses vectors?

Comment: @Ibrahim Thank you. I mean something like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#An_algebraic_proof), as cross product is only for 3d vectors in terms of geometry.

Comment: You can still use the cross product considering your equation representing a line embedded in a three-dimensional space. @JakeMZ

Comment: Wait you changed something about the labels of the terms in the cross product, but not in the way I intended. I think the vectors that should go into the cross product are $p_1 - p_0$ and $p_2 - p_0$. From a geometric perspective that makes the most sense. The cross product is the surface area of the parallelogram spanned by these to vectors. Note that one corner of of this parallelogram is $p_0$ and two others are $p_1$ and $p_2$. You divide this area by the lenght of the diagonal of the parallelogram that runs from $p_1$ to $p_2$ (ctd in next comment)

Comment: naturally the outcome of the division is half the length of the other diagonal. That is to say: the distance from $p_0$ to the point where the diagonals cross. But since they cross orthogonally and since the diagonal that runs from $p_1$ to $p_2$ is part of the line, half the other diagonal is exactly the distance from $p_0$ to that line!

Comment: So this is a 'geometric' proof if you will

Comment: To convert it into an algebraic one you might want to look up on e.g. wikipedia why the length of the cross product equals the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors

Comment: O wait... I see now that your labeling also works. You get a different parallelogram (where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are on ajecent sides and $p_0$ and $p_2$ on opposite sides rather than the other way around) so that the quantity you need to multiply the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ by to get the surface area is no longer half a diagonal but rather a altitude - but this thing is still the distance from $p_0$ to the line through $p_1$ and $p_2$ so we are fine.

Comment: Ok, so the formula works and this is a geometric proof (sketch) but translating it into an algebraic one boils down to understanding the relation between the algebraic expression for the cross product and its geometric interpretation as an area

Answer (score 1):

Okay let me type the geometric proof from the comments in more clear language

The terms in the cross product represent vectors from $p_1$ to $p_0$ and $p_2$ respectively. The cross product then gives you the area of the parallelogram spanned by these two vectors.

We know from high school how we can compute the surface area of a parallelogram: take one side (the vector $p_2 - p_1$) and the altitude line from the opposing corner of the parallelogram ($p_0$) to that side and multiply their lengths.

Now the length of the altitude is the quantity you want to compute, the desired distance. The length of the side $p_2 - p_1$ is the $L^2$-norm you have in the denominator. So we get:

The desired quantity times the norm of $p_2 - p_1$ equals the cross product of $(p_2 - p_1)$ and $(p_0 - p_1)$.

The equation then follows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even though your the equation has two variables, $x$, $y$, which you would at first be led to think that it lies in a two-dimensional space, say $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. In order to be able to use "cross product" that is defined in three-dimensional space, you have to consider the equation as something that is defined in three-dimensional space. Hence, this equation represents a plane in a three-dimensional space with its $z$ variable is equal to $0$ as in $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ with $z = 0$.

Secondly, your vector-valued equation for distance above,

$$( \mathbf{p_2-p_1}) \times (\mathbf{p_0-p_1}) / ||( \mathbf{p_2-p_1}) ||$$

requires a little correction as it is supposed to produce a scalar value rather than a vector. Because cross product outputs a vector, and its scalar multiple is still a vector. Therefore, the correct form becomes,

$$\frac{|| (\mathbf{p_2-p_1}) \times (\mathbf{p_0-p_1}) ||}{||(\mathbf{p_2-p_1}) ||}$$

From comments above I assume you meant to derive this equation using vector algebra. If so, let $\mathbf{p_0}$, $\mathbf{p_1}$ and $\mathbf{p_2}$ represent "vectors" from origin in $\mathbb{R^3}$. We also have the magnitude relation of cross product,
$$|| \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} || = || \mathbf{a}|| \ || \mathbf{b}|| \ |sin( \theta)| \tag{1}$$

If we subtract $\mathbf{p_1}$ from $\mathbf{p_2}$, we get a vector stretching along a line, which can be described by the equation $\mathbf{p_1} + t \ ( \mathbf{p_2-p_1})$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Multiplying that vector with the multiplicative inverse of its magnitude,

$$\frac{1}{|| \mathbf{p_2-p_1}||}$$

we get a unit vector, say $\mathbf{ \hat n}$,

$$\mathbf{ \hat n} = \frac{\mathbf{p_2-p_1}}{|| \mathbf{p_2-p_1}||}$$

in the same direction as $\mathbf{p_2-p_1}$. We can also write another vector, $\mathbf{p_0-p_1}$, originating from $\mathbf{p_1}$ to $\mathbf{p_0}$. With $\mathbf{ \hat n}$ and $\mathbf{p_0-p_1}$, using relation $(1)$ we can write,

\begin{align}
|| \mathbf{ \hat n} \times ( \mathbf{p_0-p_1}) || &= || \mathbf{ \hat n}|| \ || \mathbf{p_0-p_1}|| \ |sin( \theta)| \\
&= || \mathbf{p_0-p_1}|| \ |sin( \theta)| \\
&= \frac{|| (\mathbf{p_2-p_1}) \times (\mathbf{p_0-p_1}) ||}{||(\mathbf{p_2-p_1}) ||}
\end{align}

which geometrically corresponds to the perpendicular distance of $\mathbf{p_0}$ to the line. Notice how $\mathbf{ \hat n}$ was written in alternative terms in the equation above.

Comment: Thank you so much. How does $$|| \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} || = || \mathbf{a}|| \ || \mathbf{b}|| \ |sin( \theta)| $$ relate to $$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$ where $\mathbf{a} $ is a vector while $a$ is a scalar?

Comment: Here I just wanted to point out how you can think of the equation in three-dimensional case based on your comment above in response to other person concerning cross product. The two above is not directly related to each other. The part starting with _"Secondly,"_ in my explanation is, I believe, what you asked for.